# SQL query to display records with no related record within a specific date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008 R2
I have two tables. One Main records and the other is Notes related to the Main with a common key field sysid and main_id. (there can be many notes to one Main record)

I want to list records in the Main table that do NOT have a record created in the Notes table in the last 30 days related to that record.

> Main Table FIELDS > file_number, sysid
>
> Notes Table FIELDS > note_date, main_id

I have tried a hundred different suggestions from searching and nothing gives me what I need.
I think the below is what was closest but it gives only records where no note exists at all and I dont see main records that have existing notes but dont have any in the last 30 days.
I get the same results if I take out the `AND db.notes.[date] > DATEADD(dd,-30,getdate()))` line.

```
SELECT *
  FROM db.main
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
       FROM db.notes
       WHERE db.main.sysid = db.notes.main_id AND db.notes.[date] > DATEADD(dd,-30,getdate()))
 ORDER BY db.main.ile_number
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**** Client has asked for an additional column. Last note date. So they want list of main records with no notes in x days AND what was the date of the last note.

Comment: THANK YOU! this worked, I think. The only way to confirm is to go one by one through 20,000 records and see if a note is there. I only had to edit a little bit of it to work with my data. The date field is not in date format it is x days after 12/28/1800 but I used a formula to convert it and it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
select * 
from db.main m
left outer join db.notes n on m.sysid = n.main_id 
    and n.[date] > dateadd(dd, -30, getdate())) 
where n.main_id is null
order by m.ile_number
```

Comment: my client has asked for an additional column. Last note date. So they want list of main records with no notes in x days AND what was the date of the last note on the same report.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

SELECT *

FROM db.main

WHERE sysid NOT IN

```
(select main_id FROM notes)
```

UNION

SELECT *

FROM db.main

WHERE sysid NOT IN

```
(select main_id 

FROM notes 

WHERE notes.[date] > DATEADD(dd,-30,getdate())

)
```

Comment: This didnt work. It gave me an error "The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable." Thanks anyway.