# Django Query where related doesn't exist within date range

Tags: django

I have django models like:

```
class Client(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    (there are fields here)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    date = models.DateField()
    (more fields)
```

I'm trying to write a django query that returns all Clients who DON'T have an appointment in a specific date range that are of a specific type.

I found this question, which seems to be asking something similar in straight sql, but I'm trying to figure out how (and if) I can do it with django filters.

[SQL query to display records with no related record within a specific date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837172/sql-query-to-display-records-with-no-related-record-within-a-specific-date-range)

Comment: try: `Client.objects.exclude(appointment_set__date__range(mindate,maxdate))` assuming appointment_set is the default name for the inverse property, since you did not specify in the current source code.

Comment: Client.objects.exclude() sould list all the clients but those having `appointment_set` elemnets satisfying the dates being in certain range

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot resolve keyword 'appointment_set' into field."

Comment: okay. in your `models.ForeignKey(Client)` (I insist, told you in my comment :p) add a related_name= parameter. e.g. `models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="appointments")`, and use the same name: `Client.objects.exclude(appointments__date__range=(mindate,maxdate))`. I had an error in the first comment: forgot an equal sign.